# Using an SSLContext to create a SocketChannel

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, channel, socketchannel

I'm looking to implement NIO for a SSL socket. However, every example that I've found, uses SocketChannel.open() to get the socket channel.

From a SSLContext, how can I get a SocketChannel?

Comment: Got it working with Netty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately not very easy. You can't directly create a `SocketChannel` that automatically uses SSL from an `SSLContext`.

From the `SSLContext`, you can create an `SSLEngine`, and you'll have to call it appropriately to handle the SSL handshake. This isn't a matter of a few lines of code.

I have an [sslclient example](https://github.com/jesperdj/sslclient) on GitHub with a class [`SSLSocketChannel`](https://github.com/jesperdj/sslclient/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jesperdj/sslclient/SSLSocketChannel.java) which shows how to do this.

Comment: I decided to go for Netty :) Got it working with client side auth too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The question doesn't make sense. `SocketChannels` are plaintext. `SSLContexts` are for SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, that is impossible to do with the standard Java library.

SSL/TLS is implemented in Java using SSLEngine, but that class is seriously hard to use correctly.

But there are options. [TLS Channel](https://github.com/marianobarrios/tls-channel) is a simple library that does exactly that: wrapping a SSLContext (or SSLEngine) and exposing a ByteChannel interface, doing the heavy lifting internally.

(Disclaimer: I am the library's main author).